# Android SharedPreferences set/retrieve checkbox with HashMap/For each loop

Tags: android, foreach, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I was saving the checkbox text and `isChecked` into the `SharedPreferences` with using `for each loop` to get the checkbox value and I use `HashMap` to store all the value.

**The code for I save the checkbox text and isChecked:**

```
 HashMap<String,Object> amenityMap = new HashMap<>();

   for(CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes){
        if(checkBox.isChecked()){
            amenityMap.put(checkBox.getText().toString().trim(),true);
        }
    }

    saveHashMapSharedPreferences(parentActivity, amenityMap, Amenity.AMENITY_DETAILS,Amenity.AMENITY_DETAILS);
```

**Method for SharedPreference:**

```
public static void saveHashMapSharedPreferences(Activity parentActivity,HashMap<String,Object> amenityMap,String spType, String key) {
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = parentActivity.getSharedPreferences(spType, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(amenityMap); //tasks is an ArrayList instance variable
    prefsEditor.putString(key, json);
    prefsEditor.apply();
}
```

**The picture below is the checkbox value save in SharedPreferences .xml:**

[image]

So the **key** of it is `amenityDetails`, the value of checkbox are all there.

How do I can retrieve the checkbox value from this SharedPreference and set back to the checkbox where it is isChecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all change following:**

`HashMap<String,Object> amenityMap = new HashMap<>();`

to

`HashMap<String,Boolean> amenityMap = new HashMap<>();`

**Change your for each loop as follows:**

```
for(CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes){
     amenityMap.put(checkBox.getText().toString().trim(),checkBox.isChecked());    
}
```

**You can then retrieve values as follows:**

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = parentActivity.getSharedPreferences(spType, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Boolean>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Boolean> storedAmenityMap = gson.fromJson(appSharedPrefs.getString(key,""), type);
```

**Then whenever you want to set the Checkbox state:**

```
checkBoxObj.setChecked(storedAmenityMap.get(checkBoxObj.getText()));
```

Comment: I retrieve the error with 'java.lang.NullPointerException: cannot unbox null value' on checkBoxObj.setChecked(storedAmenityMap.get(checkBoxObj.getText()));

Comment: @TommyChong Ensure you have stored the data correctly in your shared preferences

Comment: Thanks you Bro, I think I get it what you means haha, nice coding and solution. I have solved it.

Comment: @TommyChong no problem. Enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

First your `HashMap` should be `HashMap<String, boolean>`.
To restore, you can also use `Gson` to parse saved data to `HashMap` again and use your restored `HashMap` to restore `CheckBox` states

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, boolean>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, boolean> hashMap = gson.fromJson(appSharedPrefs.getString(key,""), collectionType);
```